# Extract certain array elements with its parent keys using jq

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I would like to know how to use jq to extract patterns from a .json file

```
echo '{"parts": [{"name":"core","items":"garbage with ITEM1 ITEM2 and more"},{"name":"misc","items":"ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM5 bla bla"} ]}' | jq '.parts | .[] | .items |=split(" ")'
{
  "name": "core",
  "items": [
    "garbage",
    "with",
    "ITEM1",
    "ITEM2",
    "and",
    "more"
  ]
}
{
  "name": "misc",
  "items": [
    "ITEM3",
    "ITEM4",
    "ITEM5",
    "bla",
    "bla"
  ]
}
```

I think in splitting the items, but I don't know how to extract each ITEMx.

I want to obtain this output:

```
{ "core","ITEM1" }
{ "core","ITEM2" }
{ "misc","ITEM3" } 
{ "misc","ITEM4" }
{ "misc","ITEM5" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is not valid JSON.

Do you want the words form an array under the value of the `.name` field?

```sh
jq '.parts[] | {(.name): (.items | split(" "))}'
```

```json
{
  "core": [
    "garbage",
    "with",
    "ITEM1",
    "ITEM2",
    "and",
    "more"
  ]
}
{
  "misc": [
    "ITEM3",
    "ITEM4",
    "ITEM5",
    "bla",
    "bla"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TfgVhWyUrn)

Or do you want each word to form a separate object?

```sh
jq '.parts[] | (.items | split(" "))[] as $word | {(.name): $word}'
```

```json
{"core":"garbage"}
{"core":"with"}
{"core":"ITEM1"}
{"core":"ITEM2"}
{"core":"and"}
{"core":"more"}
{"misc":"ITEM3"}
{"misc":"ITEM4"}
{"misc":"ITEM5"}
{"misc":"bla"}
{"misc":"bla"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2WQfbV5RSu)

To only capture words that match the regex `ITEM\d+`, you could employ the `scan` function instead of splitting:

```sh
jq '.parts[] | {(.name): .items | scan("ITEM\\d+")}'
```

```json
{"core":"ITEM1"}
{"core":"ITEM2"}
{"misc":"ITEM3"}
{"misc":"ITEM4"}
{"misc":"ITEM5"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-aZmbO0BOC)

Answer (score 0):

Building on your attempt, we could try:

```
.parts
| .[]
| .items |= (split(" ") | map(select(test("ITEM"))))
| {(.name): .items[]}
```

This produces a stream of objects such as `{"core":"ITEM1"}`. If you really want the non-JSON output shown in the Q, it's easy enough to add the additional step.